# Error while installing rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

So I have ruby 2.2.0 installed on a VPS and I'm trying to install rails. The only problem is, when I do a gem install rails it fails. I tried it with the backtrace and the following is what I get:

```
usera@node3:~$ gem install --backtrace rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SocketError)
    getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:791:in `send'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:791:in `send'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:672:in `request'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:528:in `block in fetch_resource'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1096:in `block (3 levels) in resolv'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1094:in `each'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1094:in `block (2 levels) in resolv'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1093:in `each'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1093:in `block in resolv'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1091:in `each'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1091:in `resolv'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:519:in `fetch_resource'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:509:in `each_resource'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:490:in `getresource'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:92:in `api_endpoint'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:46:in `api_uri'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:85:in `dependency_resolver_set'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:23:in `block in pick_sets'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:22:in `pick_sets'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:28:in `find_all'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:151:in `find_all'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:54:in `add_always_install'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:463:in `resolve_dependencies'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:238:in `install_gem'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:299:in `block in install_gems'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `each'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `install_gems'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:202:in `execute'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:307:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:168:in `process_args'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:138:in `run'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
        /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I also ran `gem install --backtrace -p rails` and got the following

```
usera@node3:~$ gem install --backtrace -p rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
    invalid argument: -p rails
    /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/local_remote_options.rb:27:in `block in accept_uri_http'
    /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:377:in `handle_options'
    /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:298:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:168:in `process_args'
    /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:138:in `run'
    /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
    /home/usera/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

It seems to work fine on my other VPS so I'm a bit confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I finally figured out what was going on. It turns out that the configuration file for the DNS servers had an extra comma after the IP addresses which caused it to not resolve properly. I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and the file was in /etc/resolve.conf.

Comment: Had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.10, the file is named `/etc/resolv.conf`. Thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue with CentOS 6. The file /etc/resolv.conf has nameserver 8.8..8.8. Now it works. Thanks!